# Converting terenary and boolean operators from infix to postfix

Tags: postfix-operator, infix-operator

How can I convert these two examples from infix to postfix?

```
Example 1:
max = (a > b) ? a : b

Example 2:
(a != 0) ? ((b != 0) ? True : False) : False
```

For both expressions, I thought I would just have to remove the brackets. However, when I try to convert back from postfix to infix, the expression is invalid. I know how to do simple operations:

```
Infix:     (((a + b) * (c + d) + a) * c - 6) * b

Postfix:   a b + c d + * a + c * 6 - b *
```

...but I'm not sure how to convert max and boolean expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking about '+', '-', and '*' as operations apart from
boolean operators or max / min functions, I think you could understand
the problem better by simply saying, "All of these are operators with 2 operands --
ie, they are binary operators."

Then, the problem is setting up your expression tree so that the root is an
operator ('+', '-', 'max' or whatever), and the children are operands.  Producing
infix or postfix is simply a question of how you traverse the expression tree.